# Slider is all of a sudden not working on site

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have not changed anything on my website and all of a sudden the front page slider is not working.

http://solutionsfortravel.com/

Can someone please give an recs as to why?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'? I click the arrow and it goes to the next image? What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of errors in the console - you can use Google Chrome's developer tools to look for missing files and Javascript errors.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

You can also get similar tools in Firefox, Opera and Internet Explorer (other browsers are available)

A quick look at the console shows this error, which is to do with some kind of slider library judging by it's name.

```
jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js?ver=3.3.5:12 Uncaught TypeError: d is not a function
```

You should really try and fix all the errors you're getting though

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome developers, console part shows the error:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Try to resolve this problem with datepicker